# How to define a custom decoration shape in FeynMF?

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

FeynMF comes with pre-defined decoration shapes (circle, square, triangle, etc.) used for vertices. However I need decoration shapes that are semicircles (oriented to look like a D and mirror image of D). Does anybody know how to define such shapes in FeynMF?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you put a screenshot, a figure, anything that can reproduce your question. For example I have not understood.

Comment: Hi, as Sebastiano said above, I'm not 100% sure how that would work. Is this actually a vertex where you have multiple lines meeting or lines of different types or just a decoration that is somewhere in the middle of a line of a single type?
I can probably work out solutions for either type but how to make it work will be completely opposite for the two options.

Comment: Hi Sebastiano and Staircase27, sorry for the lack of clarity. Perhaps the best way I can describe what I'm after is to consider the Feynmf command
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=empty, decor.size=1.0}{v}
which draws a circle centred at vertex v. Instead of circle placed at vertex v, I like a different shape, namely a "D" shape placed at v.